# Autocorrelation at various aggregation levels

Tags: time-series, arima, modeling, autocorrelation

I have a time series sampled at a relatively high frequency that exhibits significant short and long-term memory effects.

Looking at the standard ACF, I can see highly significant negative autocorrelation for the first 20 lags, but after that, the ACF is just noisy around zero.

I, however, can see more interesting structure in an alternative plot that I tried: the autocorrelation at the first lag with the level of aggregation varying from 1 to `n` time steps.  For example, if the raw data time series was sampled at 1 second intervals, then `n=300` means that the data is grouped and summed in 300 second bins.  In this plot, I see 3 distinct regions of significant autocorrelation: negative at low aggregation levels, positive at medium aggregation levels, and negative again at high aggregation levels.

My question is whether there is existing literature on this type of analysis, especially on whether and how it can be used to infer the structure and dynamics of the underlying data generating process.